# (Un)Calibrated Logistic Regression Fit

Tags: logistic, rms, calibration

I'm fitting a logistic regression on a large dataset (n=89260, 17 predictors) with a class imbalance (1% positive class). I've tried to follow Dr. Harrell's teachings so I fit my full pre-specified model (I don't expect any interaction between predictors):

```
Logistic Regression Model

lrm(formula = label ~ rcs(ery, 3) + rcs(hgb, 3) + rcs(htc, 3) + 
    rcs(mcv, 3) + rcs(mch, 3) + rcs(mchc, 3) + rcs(rdw, 3) + 
    rcs(leu, 3) + rcs(neu, 3) + rcs(lin, 3) + rcs(mon, 3) + rcs(eos, 
    3) + rcs(bas, 3) + rcs(plq, 3) + rcs(pct, 3) + rcs(mpv, 3) + 
    rcs(pdw, 3), data = df, x = T, y = T)

                       Model Likelihood        Discrimination    Rank Discrim.    
                             Ratio Test               Indexes          Indexes    
Obs         89260    LR chi2    3879.88        R2       0.402    C       0.954    
 FALSE      88368    d.f.            34     R2(34,89260)0.042    Dxy     0.908    
 TRUE         892    Pr(> chi2) <0.0001    R2(34,2649.3)0.766    gamma   0.910    
max |deriv| 0.002                              Brier    0.008    tau-a   0.018
```

With (I believe) good results (very low Brier score, high AUC and Dxy). Validation gave low optimism:

```
> validate(model, B=200)
Divergence or singularity in 121 samples
          index.orig training    test optimism index.corrected  n
Dxy           0.9083   0.9078  0.9060   0.0018          0.9065 79
R2            0.4017   0.4055  0.3964   0.0091          0.3925 79
Intercept     0.0000   0.0000 -0.0689   0.0689         -0.0689 79
Slope         1.0000   1.0000  0.9821   0.0179          0.9821 79
Emax          0.0000   0.0000  0.0185   0.0185          0.0185 79
D             0.0435   0.0440  0.0429   0.0012          0.0423 79
U             0.0000   0.0000  0.0000   0.0000          0.0000 79
Q             0.0435   0.0440  0.0429   0.0012          0.0423 79
B             0.0080   0.0080  0.0080  -0.0001          0.0081 79
g             1.0549   1.0569  1.0385   0.0183          1.0366 79
gp            0.0153   0.0154  0.0152   0.0002          0.0150 79
```

The calibration plot, however, looked like this:
[image: calibration plot]
Is this due to the low prevalence of the positive class? Why does it look "uncalibrated" despite the otherwise good scores above?

And finally, where can I learn more about this subject, I'm clearly lost. Thanks!